# How do you debug "No route in the route table matches the supplied values." in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I seem to run into this error all the time:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
>
> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

The stack trace is just a bunch of MVC garbage.

Obviously I am querying for a non-existent route, but how do I discover which route it was actually trying to query? I would love to know the actual URL and HTTP Method. How can I discover this?

(I'm used to Django where the attempted URL is a part of the exception and would prefer a more efficient method than viewing the source of my page and figuring it out.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)'s `RouteDebugger` utility class to get a better view what route was handled the request.

All you need to do is add a reference to the MvcContrib, and add this code to the `Global.asax`

> ```
> RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
> RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
> ```

Comment: I found this article by Phil Haack a bit more to the point. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: I also ran into the problem of "Two Consecutive Optional Parameter" routing bug in MVC 3. The RouteDebugger would correctly find the route however when running the application the problem would still be there. See article: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx for resolution.

Comment: @DaTribe Golly-gee. That was my issue exactly. Thanks for linking to that.

Comment: @Tieson T. Glad I could help. Quite an annoying issue since; it would possibly be better if the RouteDebugger didn't find the route as the problem would be consistent.

Answer (score 13):

There's a [nice route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).

Comment: Stephen Walther also talks about Route Debugging in Chapter 9 of his forthcoming book - currently available here: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/06/chapter-2-understanding-routing.aspx

Comment: To make this to work: 1) reference RouteDebug.dll 2) Add this to the end of your Application_Start method: RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes); 3) Rejoice

Answer (score 3):

You can use return Redirect("/Home/index") instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Home","index");
```

Or

The solution for me was to pass in the Area within the route values parameter changing:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

to:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })
```

Comment: The situation for me was almost the same, I had to add the following as the third parameter: `new { area = string.Empty })`